# Use physical keyboard in tablet mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, dell-inspiron, tablet

I have a Dell Inspiron computer, which has a tablet mode. However, putting my laptop into tablet mode disables the physical keyboard. Is there any way I can turn it back on?

So far, I've tried the following things:

1. Disabling tablet mode completely. However, when I fold my laptop, it says in "desktop mode", but the keyboard is disabled.
2. Disabling the "Intel Integrated Sensor Solutions" driver in the Device Manager.
3. Disabling the touchscreen altogether.

However, none of the above methods work in any combination. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to stop Sensor Monitoring Service first and then Sensor Service.

Comment: @harrymc no luck with that--I stopped them through the command line with `sc queryex`, but I don't think they were running in the first place, since their Startup Type was listed as "Manual (Trigger Start)". I tried changing their startup type to "Disabled", but that hasn't seemed to work either.

Comment: Microsoft didn't intend for this to be possible.